Spacing issue in javascript canvas and dxf file conversion
I'm working on a web application that involves generating shapes on a canvas based on user input and then converting those shapes into DXF files. However, I'm encountering a spacing issue between shapes on the canvas and in the resulting DXF file. Here's a  version of my code:
html
<body style="background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);">
    <center>
    <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif;">Cutit App</h1>
    <button id="generatePDFButton" style="border-radius: 09px;">Generate PDF</button>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</center>
    <script>
        // Shape class to represent shapes with properties
        class Shape {
            constructor(shapeType, width, height, x, y) {
                this.shapeType = shapeType;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            addToCanvas(canvas) {
                let shape;
                const scaledWidth = this.width * SCALE_FACTOR;
                const scaledHeight = this.height * SCALE_FACTOR;
                const scaledX = this.x * SCALE_FACTOR;
                const scaledY = this.y * SCALE_FACTOR;

                if (this.shapeType === "rectangle") {
                    shape = new fabric.Rect({
                        left: scaledX,
                        top: scaledY,
                        width: scaledWidth,
                        height: scaledHeight,
                        fill: 'blue'
                    });
                } else if (this.shapeType === "circle") {
                    shape = new fabric.Circle({
                        radius: Math.min(scaledWidth, scaledHeight) / 2,
                        left: scaledX,
                        top: scaledY,
                        fill: 'red'
                    });
                } 
                canvas.add(shape);
            }
        }

        // Function to add shapes based on URL parameters
        function addShapesFromURLParams() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const data = urlParams.get("data");
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

            jsonData.forEach(data => {
                const sheet_height = data.sheet_height;
                const sheet_width = data.sheet_width;
            
                var canvas_id = document.getElementById("canvas");  
                canvas_id.width = parseInt(sheet_width)
                canvas_id.height = parseInt(sheet_height)

                const parts = data.parts;
                if (parts) {
                    parts.forEach(part => {
                        const newPart = new Shape(part.type, part.width, part.height, part.x, part.y);
                        newPart.addToCanvas(canvas);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        // Call the function to add shapes from URL parameters
        addShapesFromURLParams();

        // Function to generate PDF
        function generatePDF() {
            const objects = getAllObjectsFromCanvas();
            console.log("object" + objects.toString())
            
            const data = {
                sheet_width: canvas.width / SCALE_FACTOR,
                sheet_height: canvas.height / SCALE_FACTOR,
                objects: objects
            };


            fetch(
                'https://cutit-converter.onrender.com/generate_pdf/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                    }
                    return response.blob();
                    })
                    .then(blob => {
                    // Handle the response blob, e.g., download the file
                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'generated_pdf.pdf';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                    console.error('There was an error!', error);
                    });

                    fetch(
                'https://cutit-converter.onrender.com/generate_dxf/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                    }
                    return response.blob();
                    })
                    .then(blob => {
                    // Handle the response blob, e.g., download the file
                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'generated_dxf.dxf';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                    console.error('There was an error!', error);
                    });
        }

        // Event listener for generating PDF
        document.getElementById('generatePDFButton').addEventListener('click', generatePDF);
    </script> 
</body>

this is the resulting images : [this is the image of the dxf file generated by the server and the website screenshot of the shapes ](https://i.sstatic.net/9UxeWtKN.png)
In this code, shapes are added to the canvas based on URL parameters. However, when shapes are generated, there is unexpected spacing between them on the canvas. Additionally, when I convert the canvas content into a DXF file, the spacing between shapes remains, resulting in inaccurate placement.
I suspect the issue might be related to scaling or positioning of shapes, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this spacing issue in both canvas rendering and DXF file conversion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
In attempting to address the spacing issue between shapes on the canvas and in the resulting DXF file,

You’re trying to scale each individual object imported but that’s a messy and erroneous approach!
Instead, you should scale the canvas itself, one-off and start importing using the object's original drawing dimensions, like this...
function Drawing2Canvas(Width,Height,Scale){

var C=document.createElement('canvas'), Cx=C.getContext('2d');

Cx.imageSmoothingEnabled=true; Cx.imageSmoothingQuality='high';

C.width=Math.round(Width*Scale);

C.height=Math.round(Height*Scale);


// The canvas is now scaled and ready to start receiving the foreign objects exactly as they are in the drawing


}

Function usage...
Drawing2Canvas(4000,3000,1.357); <-- The 1.357 is the pixel scaling choice that needs to be made

NB: All the above is untested pseudo-code.
More about the "1.357"... you have to make a decision... what should a pixel represent?

A. 1mm = 1px
B. 1cm = 1px
C. 1" = 1px
D. 0.25" = 1px

When you finally test...
Has the canvas come out too big for the screen? No problems… increase the scale factor!
Has the canvas come out too small for the screen? No problems… decrease the scale factor!
Get it? :)
